# MySQL create table name from string

Tags: mysql, string, stored-procedures, create-table

I want to create a table name in MySQL but use a string value I've declared. Is this possible? I'm thinking of something like this:

```
DECLARE new_table_name VARCHAR(255);
SET new_table_name = CONCAT("foo",123);
CREATE TABLE new_table_name (
    ...etc...
)
```

So far, I can't figure out how to do this. Btw I've got this in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code in your stored procedure:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE new_table_name VARCHAR(255);
SET new_table_name = CONCAT("foo",123);

SET @createTable = CONCAT("CREATE TABLE ", new_table_name, "(id int, some_col varchar(55))");

PREPARE createStmt FROM @createTable;
EXECUTE createStmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE createStmt;

END$$
```